# Excel won't recognise text string as a date

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-format

I'm trying to import a great many dates from an external source which contains the date field as text in the format:-

Sep 23, 2021

Sep 22, 2021

etc.
I want Excel to recognise these dates as being dates but unfortunately, it does not, it still treats them as text.
I've tried splitting it into 3 separate columns and then using DATE(Y,M,D) to assign the year month and date columns, but it fails as I think it won't recognise 'Sep' as a month.
What can I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you just type 23-09-2021 or 2021/09/23 or whatever the short format is in your local, it will properly set it as date and automatically assign the data format to that cell.

Comment: @LPChip, I think you misunderstand, my issue is that Excel has a date recognition problem, not a date diplay format problem. I've told it to format the cells as date, but because it doesn't recognise them as dates it won't display them as dates.

Comment: Two things… check to see whether there are any other characters in your strings? Excel 2011 automatically sees `sep 22, 2021` as a date. But if you have a space in front of it (just one example) then it does not. I think this applies to most versions of excel. Second, date() requires that the month be a number. Try `DATE(C9,SUBSTITUTE(D9,"sep",9),E9)`.

Comment: @TopCat no I understood you correctly. Basically if excel does not see the date, re-entering it into the cell often does the trick, but sometimes you need to write it in a different format. Once excel recognizes the cell as a date, it applies the date format to the cell and if you set that to a number, it is changed to a 5 digit number instead of the date you entered. If you have a date with a space though, changing the cell to a number will not change it at all, it remains the same string. Also, if the cell starts with ` the cell is always treated as a string. The ` becomes invisible though.

Comment: @Mockman, thanks for the suggestion, but Excel does not recognise sep 22, 2021 as a date for me! Is this a UK/USA regional difference perhaps (I'm in the UK).

Comment: So that would probably depend on your system preferences > language & region > advanced > dates settings. You didn't say how this affects other months.

Comment: Did you check if your region date setting is correct?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with UK settings for dates.  To check the actual contents of the string, (if,  for example, you string is in `B1`) enter `=CODE(MID(B1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(B1))),1))` (and fill down if it doesn't Spill) and post back with the series of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Any of a number of solutions are available.

To begin though, if Excel has no reason to believe it is a date, it simply won't treat it as one. How does it come to believe something is a date? Broadly, based upon the WINDOWS settings on the computer in question. Most Windows settings include date formats that recognize common arrangement and separator patterns when the data are all numerical digits, but even then Windows rears its ugly head.

Note:  There is absolutely NO setting in Excel you can use to change this behavior.

You can change cell formatting, but if it thinks you pasted the equivalent of "Santa Claus", it will not treat it as a date and the formatting will not be triggered.

For example, my Windows settings understand "Sep 21, 2021" as a date, but not "21 Sep, 2021". The former is converted into a date regardless of my desire while the second is not, again regardless of my desire.

So one solution would be to change your Windows time formatting settings. AND all your spreadsheet's users' Windows time formatting settings. Gonna guess that's a complete non-starter though.

Another solution would be to use VBA to create macros that trigger upon pasting into the cell in question. For each of the cells in question. Or a single one that tests all cells in a list upon pasting anywhere. Or something a bit cleverer but not markedly different. But VBA is a skill one must have prior to using it and many organizations won't let it be used anyway.

Moving on one has basically two approaches:

1. Change the data being pasted. Either before it is even copied (so, get the originator of it to change it for you) or after being copied, but before being presented to your spreadsheet.
2. Paste it as is, then operate upon it to generate the date, formatted as you wish.

For the first, "external source" tolls like a death knell on the "before it is even copied" front. However, you can do some clunky, time-consuming things for the "after being copied" part. You could use a text editor, many of which have full or full-ish RegEx capabilities, to paste and rearrange the data to a form Excel will see as a date. Or have an import page in your spreadsheet that you dump all the material into and it takes out the needed bits and does any rearranging.

Yikes. Not my cup of tea.

You could paste it wherever you paste it now (you DO seem willing to do that), and operate on it with a VBA UDF, but that brings up the "skill in using VBA" and "is VBA even allowed to begin with" problems.

So, perhaps a nice formula? You already know how to tear it apart and use the pieces. What seems to not be working is the putting it back together in a form Excel will do the right thing with. In other words, after you do the part where you put it together, how do you get it to recognize "Sep" as a month?

`DATEVALUE()` is your friend here. Just create the string and wrap that formula with `DATEVALUE()` and it will convert. Um, oh, yeah... if the string is recognized by Windows as a date...

Well, two things:

1. Just put the string together in a form you see WILL work for you in Excel. So if "Sep 23, 2021" won't work, see if "23 Sep, 2021" will work. Some small experimentation will find a form you can use if you want to do the minimum. For example, I found "21 Sep, 2021" flat would not work. (The Europeanized version of "Sep 21, 2021".) But if I simply left out the comma, that form worked beautifully, both as a string pasted (which you can't do, obviously, as it doesn't come that way!) and as a string put together for `DATEVALUE()`. Just not putting in that comma made it something Windows and therefore Excel, saw as a date.
2. Don't mess with the "Sep" at all. Paste the string, tear it apart, but put the "Sep" portion through a change into "9" or "09". A simple table of months vs. month number in some out of the way place would do the trick, or in the ultimate out of the way place:  a Named Range. Coupla ways you can fill the Named Range.

But even easier than the lookup table approach, even if the table is stuffed into a wonderful Named Range (love those things), is just to create a list of dates that has a date from each month, use `TEXT()` to change the internal result array into three letter month abbreviations, and use a `MATCH()` or `XMATCH()` to find the "row" the text you get for the month matches. So something like so:

```
=MATCH("Sep",  TEXT(SEQUENCE(12) & "/01/2021","mmm"),  0)
=MATCH("Sep",  TEXT(ROW(1:12) & "/01/2021","mmm"),  0)
```

It will create a sequence from 1 to 12, attach the day and year to it allowing Excel to realize it's a list of dates, then change it to text formatted to the month abbreviations. "Sep" will be the 9th item in the list so looking it up will return a "9". That gives you the "9" to use in `DATEVALUE()` so you put the pieces together using this 9 and the day and year you can extract currently, and you have values Excel will fall all over itself to make a date from. Any order you find works.

I promise, just creating a string using "Sep" directly, as mentioned earlier, will work if you experiment to find the order of elements your system will see as a date, but this method does add the idea that it works nicely because you won't have an urge to add or preserve commas when using only numbers and you're familiar with what order of number elements will definitely give you a recognized date. So, either way.

Or you could simply use this hammer:

```
=DATEVALUE( SUBSTITUTE(A1,  ",",  "") )
```

or one much like it if, as for me, the comma sometimes makes a difference.